# How do I use grpc_impl::ServerAsyncReader::read?

Tags: c++, grpc

I am trying to use grpc C++ to setup a client -> server streaming scenario. My service is written in async way.

From the server side I got a `ServerAsyncReader` object after receiving the call, which has a `read` function. However, this function does not have any return value. How do I know how many times I should call this function? What if I read more than I should, or faster than the client writes? The [doc](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_async_reader.html#abc05433351dff99d1686ec796573d94a) just simply says this reads a message, but does not mention any error-handling if it's called more / faster than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a86d9810ced694e50f7987ac90b9f8c1a

> Client-side Read, Server-side Read, Client-side RecvInitialMetadata (which is typically included in Read if not done explicitly): ok indicates whether there is a valid message that got read. If not, you know that there are certainly no more messages that can ever be read from this stream. For the client-side operations, this only happens because the call is dead. **For the server-sider operation, though, this could happen because the client has done a WritesDone already**.

Comment: Mention where does the URL in your post redirect to.